# How can I set state in one page based on some result in background page in React native?

Tags: android, react-native

For example, I have a download manager to download something in a class and will run as foreground service in android using headless js.

I would like to have a page to display the status of the download.

However, the page component will be mounted or unmounted due to user actions.

So how can I hook the downloading status, which will be stored in the download manager class and display it in the page whenever user open the page?

I tried whenever the page's components is mounted, I pass the pointer to the download manager.
But it seems not work. Below is what I tried

Download Manager:

```
class DownloadManager{
    public static pointer;


    async download() {
        //download code
        //when download update
        DownloadManager.pointer.setState({status:status})
    }
}
```

my page:

```
class BackupPage extends React.Component<any, any> {

    componentDidMount() {
        DownloadManager.pointer = this
    }

    render() {
        //render code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PubSub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js).

```js
class DownloadManager{
    public static pointer;


    async download() {
        //download code
        //when download update
        PubSub.publish('download-complete', {status:true});
    }
}

class BackupPage extends React.Component<any, any> {

    componentDidMount() {
        PubSub.subscribe('download-complete', (msg, data) => {
            this.setState({ status :data.status})
        })
    }

    render() {
        //render code
    }
}
```