# How to get Native Module return value?

Tags: android, react-native

I want this promise value in `App.js` class with button click. Please help me in finding out the solution.

```
@ReactMethod
public void initTimerService(Promise promise)
{
    TimerService timerService = App42API.buildTimerService();
    String timerName = "<Enter_your_timer_name>";
    long timeInSeconds= 120;
    timerService.createOrUpdateTimer(timerName, timeInSeconds, new App42CallBack() {
        public void onSuccess(Object r)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"response = " + r);
            Timer timer = (Timer)response;
            promise.resolve(timer.getName());
            System.out.println("Timer Name is: " + timer.getName());
            System.out.println("Time is: " + timer.getTimeInSeconds());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please refer to this answer about Pubsub on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60719779/2427715).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void initTimerService(Callback callback)
{

  TimerService timerService = App42API.buildTimerService();
  String timerName = "<Enter_your_timer_name>";
  long timeInSeconds= 120;
  timerService.createOrUpdateTimer(timerName, timeInSeconds, new 
    App42CallBack() {
     public void onSuccess(Object r)
      {
        Log.e(TAG,"response = "+r);
        Timer timer = (Timer)response;
        promise.resolve(timer.getName());
        System.out.println("Timer Name is: "+timer.getName());
        System.out.println("Time is: "+timer.getTimeInSeconds());
        callback.invoke(true);
    }

});
```

}

Comment: Can you please help me with code because i am new in React-Native